# All vagrant commands fail with "Bundler, the underlying system used to manage Vagrant plugins"

Tags: vagrant

Whenever I run any vagrant command, it fails, with the following error message, regardless of whether or not I'm in a vagrant folder, or any other folder.

What's the problem?

```
$ vagrant box list

Bundler, the underlying system used to manage Vagrant plugins,
is reporting that a plugin or its dependency can't be found.
This is usually caused by manual tampering with the 'plugins.json'
file in the Vagrant home directory. To fix this error, please
remove that file and reinstall all your plugins using `vagrant
plugin install`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure which file was causing the issue, but I simply removed my `~/.vagrant.d` folder, and that fixed it for me.

I suspect you could possibly just remove the `~/.vagrant.d/plugins.json` file and that might work as well.

You could of course just try renaming the above instead of deleting them to try it out yourself!